# build failed: exit code 127

Tags: reactjs, detox

created my project with my app

This is the project.json file. That I have created

```
{
  "name": "detox",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:e2e":"navicotrackapp test",
    "test:e2e:build":"navicotrackapp build"

  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/navicotrackapp.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/navicotrackapp.xcodeproj -scheme navicotrackapp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone XR"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However.  When I ran the test this was the out come:

[image]

Questions:

1. What did I do wrong
2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7):

**For those coming with `yarn 127` error code problem**

Take a look on https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/711
Most probably you just need to run in console `yarn` :)

Answer (score 2):

Try below commands it works for me

- `$ npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`
- `$ ionic serve`

Answer (score 2):

Just use https://app.netlify.com/drop to deploy manually on `Netlify`

first run this command

```
npm run build 
OR 
yarn run build
```

Then drag and drop the build folder on the website above.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, and please take care of the spaces.

It worked for me though. I added CI= in the capital before `npm run build`. Double-check if you did git add. , `git commit -m "first commit"` and `git push -u origin` before your final deployment.

[image: Please check this netlify application image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `scripts` values with these, and try again:

```
"scripts": {
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:e2e":"npm run test",
    "test:e2e:build":"npm run build"  // THIS SCRIPT WILL STILL BREAK FOR YOU
},
```

The last two are the important ones!

You need to prefix a script command with `npm run` or `yarn` if the script references another script in your `package.json`.

So instead of a script calling `navicotrackapp test` it would call `npm run test` OR `yarn test`.

---

NOTE:

In you example it looks like the terminal is failing on the script `navicotrackapp build`. Know that you do not have a `build` script defined so if you replace the script with `npm run build` it will still fail. You'll need to add a `build` script in if you want it to work!

```
"scripts": {
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "build": // DO SOMETHING HERE!!!!,
    "test:e2e":"npm run test",
    "test:e2e:build":"npm run build"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I removed my package.json file and re-run yarn. It worked for me